# XML/XSLT get infromation base on other element's attribute

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, attributes

I have 2 XML files and both of them have identical attribute in them.
My goal is to use 1st file's attribute to gather information with same ID from the 2nd file.

What i want is the xsl file will use m@id(there are three) in 1.xml to gather correct information from 2.xml
E.g.: first id in xml 1 is 002 and it will only collect names from the second  element where m@id = 002;

Here are my XML code

1.XML

```
<ms
    <m id="002">
    </m>
    <m id="001">
    </m>
    <m id="003">
    </m>
</ms>
```

2.XML

```
<cs>
  <c>
    <name>
        <firstName>Three</firstName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <lastName>Three</lastName>
    </name>
    <m id="003"></m>
  </c>

  <c>
    <name>
        <firstName>Two</firstName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <lastName>Two</lastName>
    </name>
    <m id="002"></m>
  </c>

  <c>
    <name>
        <firstName>One</firstName>
        <middleName></middleName>
        <lastName>One</lastName>
    </name>
    <m id="001"></m>
  </c>
</cs>
```

3.XSL

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('2.xml')/cs/c"/>

<xsl:template match="c">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name[m/@id=@id]"/>
  // this is just some assubmtion but i think i am wrong
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be like this:

```
Two two 002
One One 001
Three three 003
```

Comment: Please share the structure of the output XML.

Comment: Hi, ive updated the code, is this what ur looking for?

Comment: Is it just text output that you are expecting or is it html because your XSLT shows a `<p>` tag.

Comment: it it just text output, i can put them into html later on, the <p> tag is there to make my life easier lol

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Nope, I know XSLT 2.0 will make it much more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/ms">
    <xsl:for-each select="m">
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="document('2.xml')/cs/c[m/@id=current()/@id]/name" />
        <xsl:text>ID: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;First Name: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name/firstName" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;Last Name: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name/lastName" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
ID: 002
First Name: Two
Last Name: Two

ID: 001
First Name: One
Last Name: One

ID: 003
First Name: Three
Last Name: Three
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working! I will post a complete version for others later on